# How to group together tuples with the same element at a certain index?

Tags: python

I Have a list of tuples like:

```
a = [('a', 'a', 'z', 'a'), ('b', 'b', 'z', 'b'), ('c', 'c', 'c', 'c')] #... and many more
```

I need to cut all tuples from the list, where items with index `[2]` is identical
and write them to other variable.

In the end I should have:

```
a = [('c', 'c', 'c', 'c')]
b = [('a', 'a', 'z', 'a'), ('b', 'b', 'z', 'b')]
```

How can I implement this in Python?

Comment: What approach have you tried? And what error are you getting? Also what do you mean write to other var?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `itertools groupby`:

```
from itertools import groupby

k = sorted(k, key= lambda x: x[2]) # if elements are not in order
for grp,key in groupby(k, lambda x: x[2]):
    print(f'group is {grp} is with value {list(key)}')
```

**result:**

```
group is z is with value [('a', 'a', 'z', 'a'), ('b', 'b', 'z', 'b')]
group is c is with value [('c', 'c', 'c', 'c')]
```

Comment: Beware that `groupby` only groups consecutive elements that are considered equal. Something like `[('a','a','z','a'),('c','c','c','c'),('b','b','z','b')]` would fail.

Comment: @Heike then sort based on element at index 2 and then perform groupby. I guess, that will work or  I missed anything?

Comment: oh...  is there something i can do with this? elements will be not consecutive

Comment: I've already updated my answer for the same @UC

Answer (score 0):

Create a mapping of the tuples according to the item at index 2. For convenience, it is possible to use a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) of type `list`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

a = [('a','a','z','a'), ('b','b','z','b'), ('c','c','c','c')]

res = defaultdict(list)
for tup in a:
    res[tup[2]].append(tup)

print(res)
```

Will give:

```
{'z': [('a', 'a', 'z', 'a'), ('b', 'b', 'z', 'b')], 
 'c': [('c', 'c', 'c', 'c')]}
```